# Android Wear 2.0 Memory Leak

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I created a **blank Android Wear 2.0 stand-alone app project** in Android Studio. I noticed that when I run the blank app on my watch there seems to be a memory leak (shown below). Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

[image]

The device I'm testing it on is an LG Watch Style, running Android Wear 2.0

This is a **blank** project, here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.mc.memorytester">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="false"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mc.memorytester"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest and activity code?

Comment: Posted! This is a blank android wear project, which is why I find the the memory usage graph perplexing.

Comment: Can you add [leak canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to the project and retest?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like a memory leak. If you were in fact leaking, the total amount of used memory would keep increasing over time, and eventually cause a very sluggish experience and/or an `OutOfMemoryException`. What you see here are cycles of objects being created, and then garbage collected.

There are still things you can do to improve this, since frequent garbage collection might result in hiccups/lag.

My suggestion is to take a look at methods that are executed often (`onDraw()` and similar things) and make sure that you're not creating objects inside of them. If that doesn't help you can use the Android Profiler to dig deeper and find out what's being created (details about how you do that can be found e.g. [here](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8))

Comment: I've posted the code. You're probably right that this is not a memory leak, but I'm perplexed at memory usage pattern for a blank project that does nothing. The screenshot above is from the Android Profiler

Comment: That is indeed a very blank project. :) Try "Record memory allocations" in the profiler over one of those cycles and see if you can track down what type of objects are being created, and from where. But if it's not in your code you'll probably not be able to do much about it...

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Android Wear 2.0. I've reported the bug to them here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64296127